# Hiding Default Salesperson on SO form dynamically

Tags: acumatica

I have added a default lookup field for "Default SalesPerson" on SO screen  (SO301000) below Description field in my customization.

However, I want to hide this field based on certain OrderType, for example OrderType = 'TR'.
I have written below code to hide, but that is not working. Please suggest-

```html
 protected void SOOrder_OrderType_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = (SOOrder)e.Row;

        if(row.OrderType == "TR")
        {
              PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<SOOrder.salesPersonID>(cache, null, false);
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any UI presentation logic must be implemented in RowSelected handlers. Other possible, but very rare option is data view delegate. Just move your logic to RowSelected handler as shown in T200 class and the issue should be resolved.

Comment: Thank you, I have moved my code to RowSelected handler.  However, earlier in FieldUpdated also, it was working for other controls. It was only DefaultSalesPerson controls were not hiding. However, as for this scenario, I have found that DefaultSalesPerson is not a require field for OrderType TR and hence it is getting hide automatically.